# CentOS 7, SELinux, PHP, Apache: How to set default permissions to new or updated files in an directory?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7, permissions

Server info:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)  
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2014 09:44:39)  
SELinux enforcing  
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

My PHP-Script needs to read from a home directory text files. Those files are updated every 30 minutes. (from a trusted user).

Normally the permissions of those files are set to `-rw----r--.` the owner and group are the from the user who uploads the files.

There is now a case that the read permissions for others are missing. (i dont know why..) and the PHP script cant read the content:

```
file_get_contents(/home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2/file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied (2)
```

Because the group read-rights are also missing, i cant just add the `apache`-user to the `someuser`-group.

I just need to ensure that the read permissions for the apache process is given at any time.

What would be the best and securest way to do so?
Maybe setting `umask 173` to the directory or files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ACLs (access control lists) to set additional group permissions, which can be set with the `setfacl` command.  For example:

```
setfacl -dm g:apache:r /home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
```

When you do an `ls` on that directory it will show a `+` sign next to the permissions to indicate an ACL is set:

```
$ ls -ld /home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 someuser somegroup 26 Oct 10 10:17 /home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
```

You can view the ACL with the `getfacl` command.

```
$ getfacl home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
# file: home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
# owner: someuser
# group: somegroup
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:apache:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

And then when files and directories are created under there they will inherit those permissions:

```
$ cd /home/someuser/some_dir/subdir1/subdir2
$ touch moo
$ getfacl moo
# file: moo
# owner: someuser
# group: somegroup
user::rw-
group::rwx          #effective:rw-
group:apache:r-x        #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

ACLs are awesome! I highly recommend learning more about the subject:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html

Comment: i used you suggested `setfacl` command, but i am still getting the error `permission denied`.  
`getfacl` returns the same info like in your example.  
Looks like i need to enable ACLs first. I'll give you a feedback on Monday, because i cant remount the the device right now.

Comment: Ah.  Something else you can do:  Change the group ownership of the directory to 'apache' (or whatever group Apache runs as), set group to read (`chown g+rx /path/to/dir`), and set gid on the directory (`chmod g+s /path/to/dir`).  When new files are created they'll be part of that group.

Comment: Found my mistake: I gave the ACL directions to subdir1 and not subdir2.  ACL worked :)
One more question: subdir2 is synced by the user. If i understood ACL, the directions are permanent, correct?  
Or i can just set them recursively?

Comment: They are permanent until something or someone changes them.  You can use the `-R` flag with `setfacl` to apply changes recursively.

Comment: Yep, just noticed that the rules are discarded by a change.
I am getting subdir2 synced by the user. In subdir2 are again two dirs with the files i need to read. Is there a way to give those files the permissions i need? Recursivly does not seem to work. every time subdir2 is synced the acl directions are gone...

Comment: Perhaps have the user apply the ACLs after syncing, or assuming they're on Linux and are using rsync, have them set the ACLs on their end and copy with all attributes.  Otherwise just set up a cron job to find files without the necessary permissions and correct them.